# vuejs: object type of computed value can't support two-way data binding

Tags: vue.js, two-way

In my Vuejs(2.x version), I came across as following:

```
Vue.component('service',{
    template: '<div>' +
              '<div>{{serviceData.serviceName}}</div>' +  
              '<input v-model="serviceData.serviceName">' +
              '</div>',
    props: ['serviceData'],
})

var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: {
        allData: {
            serviceName: 'Service1',
            serviceType: '0',
            otherInfo: 'xxxinfo',
        },
    },
    computed: {
        serviceData() {
            return {
                serviceName: this.allData.serviceName,
                serviceType: this.allData.serviceType,
           };
        },
    },
 })

 <div id="demo">
    <service :service-data="serviceData"></service>
 </div>
```

as above, in  my Vue instance I have the original data of `alldata`, which is an object type. And since it contains some other non-related information. I created an object by  `computed` which only contains related information and name it as `serviceData`.

And pass the serviceData  object to the component `service` via `props`. 
In the `service` component, I have an input element which  two way bind to `serviceData.serviceName` with v-model.

But it turns out the two way binding can't work correctly.

So how to add reactivity in this case.

Please refer to this live demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/baoqger/t3mr9de3/1/

Comment: I think that encompasing vuex to your application would be best approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is here:https://jsfiddle.net/66ffqtej/

you can localize the date in the component ,can it can work.

```
local: this.serviceData
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can use a nested computed object. But you can use the [following](https://jsfiddle.net/t3mr9de3/2/) in general.

```
  computed: {
    serviceName: {
      get: function() {
        return this.allData.serviceName
      },
      set: function(newVal) {
        this.allData.serviceName = newVal;
      }
    }
  }
```

Doing so you obviously have to adjust the passed in `props`. Also, if you use this method, Vue will warn you about mutating passed in `props`.

A better way or basically the correct way would be to `$emit` an event in your child component through custom events and [update the data in your parent component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events) accordingly.